# Can an organization account itself issue a personal access token(Classic) in GitHub?

Tags: github

Let's say Github actions does github private package install and build on an organization repository, it should use PAT which the organization issued.I don't want PAT to be tied to an individual account because of many drawbacks.

Is there a way to issue an organization PAT(Classic)? Or do I have to sign the organization personal account up to GitHub for PAT?

*Excluding the usecase of `GITHUB_TOKEN`

Comment: PATs are always tied to a user. You could create a "machine user", which is a normal user account, but without a real human tied to it (see [here](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/types-of-github-accounts#personal-accounts)).

Comment: Thank you for your replay and reference. Could you move it to an answer post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

PATs are always tied to user accounts, so as an organization, you can't create a "stand-alone" token. The official recommendation, as per the [documentation](https://docs.github.com/en/get-started/learning-about-github/types-of-github-accounts#personal-accounts), is to create a "machine user":

> Personal accounts are intended for humans, but you can create accounts to automate activity on GitHub. This type of account is called a machine user. For example, you can create a machine user account to automate continuous integration (CI) workflows.

Handling this account is more of an administrative issue: how to share credentials, where to store the secret itself, etc.

Should you switch to GitHub Enterprise and enable single sign-on, there are some [extra considerations](https://docs.github.com/en/enterprise-cloud@latest/organizations/granting-access-to-your-organization-with-saml-single-sign-on/managing-bots-and-service-accounts-with-saml-single-sign-on) when it comes to bot users.